# How to get summation of i ∈∑ nCr where ( a <= i <= b )

Tags: math, combinations

Is there a way to get the required sum without having to iterate from a to b and summing the value of bCr + (b-1)Cr + (b-2)Cr + .... + aCr ?

Note : C stands for Choose

Comment: If a `Cr` is a constant then it is an arithmetic progression. However, it doesn't appear to be connected with `c++` because there is no *code*.

Comment: In mathematics, this is called a [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)). Your question is too general. There are many methods to calculate a series.

Comment: Is C stands for "choose? Is r constant?

Comment: Disambiguate the notation.

Comment: @DeiDei that's why I tagged C++ and asked if there was a way to do so without iterating.

Comment: @ShaharBental Choose

Comment: Yes, you can do this in O(1). Now if you tidy up the question then someone might be kind enough to answer.

Comment: I think you should remove the C++ tag...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [maths](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [hockey stick rule](http://britton.disted.camosun.bc.ca/pascal/pascal.html#hockey)

`bCr + (b-1)Cr + (b-2)Cr + .... + aCr = 
bCr + (b-1)Cr + (b-2)Cr + .... + rCr - ((a-1)Cr+(a-2)Cr+...+rCr) = 
(b+1)C(r+1)-aC(r+1)`

For example, `6+10+15=4C2+5C2+6C2=7C3-4C3=35-4`